# web3 not connecting to Infura / Rinkeby Testnet

Tags: web3js, blockchain, rinkeby, infura

I've successfully deployed my Smart-Contract to the `Rinkeby TestNet` via `Remix.` 
Everything works perfectly *from within Remix*.

But when I try to get my web DApp to fire methods in my Smart-Contract - nothing's working.

Here's my code for integrating `infura` to my DApp:

```
// WEB3 SET-UP:
if(typeof(web3) !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("Web3 provider found! Current Provider is WORKING!");
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
}
else {
    console.log("NO Web3 provider found!  Gonna set one up...");
    // This is NOT working:
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/<MY API KEY>"));

    // This is the code I was using to connect to localhost - as provided by Ganache
    // which IS working perfectly well:
    //web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
    console.log("OK, NOW we DO have a PROVIDER --> HttpProvider = ", web3.providers.HttpProvider);   
}
```

Of note:
-I did update my Contract's Address in my js code to reflect its new address on Rinkeby, so I know that's not the issue.
-The only thing that's different about this code from the version that *was* working is the `HttpProvider`.  When its set to `localhost: 8545` (provide by running `Ganache`) everything is fine. Its the switching to `rinkeby.infura.io/<MY API KEY>` that breaks things.

Comment: If you are testing with MetaMask you should be aware that since November 2nd it has changed it way to connect with dapps. https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why (because I'm a noob) but when I do

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/mykey"));
```

without the checks, it works somehow, but only with MetaMask installed. When I try it with any other web3 ready browser it just doesn't work. Really confused!

Answering because I can't yet comment and it is a working solution at least for me.